# Problemas con librería FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Estoy usando la librería FPDF para generar archivos PDF con datos traídos de la BD y guardarlo en el servidor con el siguiente código:

```
$route = 'billing/quotes/'.$numberQuote.'/'; // We will scale a variable with the path where we will store the files_post

if (!file_exists($route)) { //We validate if the folder exists. If it does not exist, it is created.
    mkdir($route, 0777, true);
}
$pdf->Output('F','billing/quotes/'.$numberQuote.'/'.$numberQuote.'.pdf');
$pdf->Output();
```

La pregunta es como hago para generar un nuevo PDF cada vez que se haga una actualización en la BD y no me reemplace el archivo que ya existe.

De antemano, gracias por la ayuda que me puedan ofrecer.

Comment: Creo que deberias instanciar la clase new de fpdf antes de realizar el save. De esta manera te va a estar creando un documento pdf nuevo por cada vez que se ejecuta el codigo. $pdf=new PDF();

Comment: Gracias por responder franco, hice tu sugerencia pero igualmente me sigue reemplazando el archivo y no me guarda el anrterior.

Comment: Al generar el archivo, puedes concatenar a su nombre un número único, puede ser con la fecha y hora o un número, sea secuencial o aleatorio, asegúrate que no se repita.

Comment: Me parece una buena opcion manejar algun tipo de id unico para identificar cada uno de ellos como dice mi compañero @DjCrazy

Comment: Quizás también podrías añadir la fecha y la hora del sistema al momento que se haga el cambio   '. date('d-m-Y') .'  <-- solo fecha, faltaría añadir el formato de hora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar este código para generar un código único y usarlo como un prefijo:

```
<?php
    function codigoUnico($longitud) {
        $clave = '';
        $caracteres = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; //caracteres a usar para generar el código
        $max = strlen($caracteres)-1; //cantidad máxima de caracteres
        for($i=0;$i < $longitud;$i++) $clave .= $caracteres{mt_rand(0,$max)};
        return $clave;
    }
    $codigo = codigoUnico(4); //genera un código de 4 caracteres de longitud.

    $route = 'billing/quotes/directorio/';

    echo 'billing/quotes/directorio/'.$codigo.'_nombreArchivo.pdf';
?>
```

Obtendrás un nombre similar a este cada vez que se ejecute el código:

> billing/quotes/directorio/rtvz_nombreArchivo.pdf

> billing/quotes/directorio/vew3_nombreArchivo.pdf

En la documentación oficial de `php` encuentras información de la función `mt_rand`: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mt-rand.php

Comment: DjCrazy muchísimas gracias. Me funcionó perfecto.